# Django - How to check all the attributes of a queryset?

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, django-models, django-users

I am looking a way to get all the attributes of a variable after we set the value in it using queryset.

For example...refer below code... using user.id or user.first_name i can get the value for that attribute. But if i want to check what all other attributes it has? Is there a way i can get.

If we use **user** then it will just return   which is what we have defined in admin.py.

## Code, i am using Django Shell

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user=User.objects.get(id=1)
user.first_name # Will return some value say testUser
user.id  # will return some value say 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django returns a tuple of fields associated with a model if you want. 
Django 3.0:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    User._meta.get_fields()
```

Comment: ._meta.get_fields(), this will return all the fields along with the relationship with other models as well.. cool. This is very helpful to check the relationship of the model. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14):

I’m guessing what you are saying is that you want to print all attributes of an **object** instead of **QuerySet**

To print all attributes of an object you can do the follow:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user=User.objects.get(id=1)
print(user.__dict__)
```

But if you just want to find out what django default user models fields are, you can check this docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/

Comment: Perfect.. this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This .__dict__ can be used to any variable (which holds the data) not just the user as above.

Comment: @MayankTripathi you should probably mark this as the answer that solved your problem then.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @MarkL 's answer:
You can pretty print it for better readability.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from pprint import pprint # new
user=User.objects.get(id=1)
pprint(user.__dict__) # new ---->  pprint() instead of print()
```

Another way which I always prefer using over `__dict__` is `vars()` method:

```
user=User.objects.get(id=1)
pprint(vars(user))
```

Both return the same result but to me **vars()** is more convenient to write than the dunder dict method i-e `__dict__`, coz I am too lazy to write 4 underscores.

Answer (score 1):

Building on MarkL's answer, here is the same thing, but with nicer formatting:

```
[f"{key}: {value}" for key, value in user.__dict__.items()]
```

(Sorry, I don't have enough rep to post this as a comment.)